# VSTS Build not generating latest bin binaries

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-definition

I am using TFS 2018 CI pipeline for MVC project, also I added the project's bin files into the TFS, there is no problem with the pipeline, its getting succeeded and artifact is generated successfully but the main problem is that if I made any changes in code related to project's DLL,

`the CI pipeline's build solution not generating its own latest bin file`

Until or unless I manually check Out the project.dll file and than check In the file than pipeline will pick the changes, what I am missing, same result by using 'MSBUILD' tasks, I also TICK clean the 'all directories' but same result

[image]

Comment: You should **never** put binaries into source control, and especially not build outputs.

Comment: @DanielMann I dint not understand why you mean by binaries?

Comment: Why not remove the bin folder from your repo, since it caused the problem. And the bin folder is not supposed to be included in the source control as Daniel commented.

Comment: if bin folder not included in source control than at TFS BUILD time, TFS throws error missing reference in cs.proj or .sln file

Comment: @ Levi Lu-MSFT, if i didnt add the bin folder into the sourse control than at time MS build its throw error, missing reference in cs.proj or .sln file

Answer (score 0):

After spending whole day I came to the solution that, bin folder should not be added/included into the Source Control (TFS/Azure),

```
 bin folder or project's binaries should not be added in to TFS
```

bin folder should be excluded in the project, after doing this operation, when I run the same build pipeline and inspect the artifact found that TFS builds added the bin folder and files accordingly, thats shocked me.

One thing should be remember in this case that what about external dlls reference, create a CommonDLLs folder at the same level of the src folder and put all external DLLs there. They are referenced through a relative path